# Upstart and process substitution

Tags: bash, upstart, redirect

So I want to use the following in my script stanza:

```
forever -l >(tee $QW_LOG_DIR/webserver.log | logger -p user.info -t '[QW]') start webserver.js
```

However, that won't work because:

1. That's bash syntax, and:
2. The `>(...)` construct creates a process before my actually creating `forever`, so upstart will track the wrong pid.

   ... at least that's what I think, I'm an upstart newbie.

My thinking is that in order to bypass both of these issues, I should use `mkfifo` in my `pre-start` stanza so that I can write to the fifo in my start script.

Questions:

1. Is that the way to go? If not -- what is?
2. If it is, then I will need to run the `(tee | logger)` part "in the background", presumably in `pre-start`?
3. Again, if so, how do I track it, and take it down in my `post-end` stanza?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to invoke a Bash script from Upstart, you can place the script in a file and invoke it through the `exec` stanza:

```
exec /bin/bash /path/to/my-bash-script.sh
```

If you place a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) at the script’s beginning and make the file executable you can even execute it directly:

```
exec /path/to/my-bash-script.sh
```